# Typescript inheritance function not same as documentation

Tags: typescript

The specification mentions that the following function will be used for extension :

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function(d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function f() { this.constructor = d; }
    f.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new f();
}
```

However the function generated currently is :

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};
```

This breaks static inheritance:

```
class A{
    fooMem=10;
    static fooStat=10;
}
class B extends A{};

var b = new B();
alert(b.fooMem.toString());
alert(B.fooStat.toString());
```

[Try It](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20A%7B%0A%09fooMem=10;%0A%09static%20fooStat=10;%0A%7D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%7B%7D;%0A%0Avar%20b%20=%20new%20B%28%29;%0Aalert%28b.fooMem.toString%28%29%29;%0Aalert%28B.fooStat.toString%28%29%29;%0A)

Which would work if the documentation mentioned extends function is used : [Test](http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/bas7X/)

Anybody know the reason why the documentation mentioned function was not used?

Comment: http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/825

Comment: The TypeScript compiler does not think that class `B` has a static member `fooStat` - that seems wrong reading the specs, but the generated JavaScript matches what the compiler thinks at least.

Comment: Thanks for identifying this and providing a manual solution for us in the mean time. This was making me crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been accepted as a bug: http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/825